# Stylesheet does not work correctly when it used in Flask framework. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm using flask framework, to make some website but when i try to write css style it apply only for body tag and ignores all next

index.html content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static', filename = 'css/style.css')}}">
</head>
<body>

<h2>some text</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

style.css content

```
body {
    background: #222;
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

when i check website source i see this

```
body {
    background: #222;
}
```

Comment: Forced a refresh (Crtl+F5) in your browser?

Comment: bruh. yes. 
restarted localserver too